# Navigate by clicking on StackNavigator header to tab inside TabNavigator nested within StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The structure looks like this:

```
StackNavigator
  --MainScreen
    --Header
      --headerRightButton
      --headerLeftButton
    --TabNavigator
      --Tab1
      --Tab2
      --Tab3
```

`Tab1` is active inside MainScreen, by pressing button on headerRightButton it should activate `Tab2`

How can I do it using `react-navigation`?